# Only can see postgreSQL as an admin

Tags: postgresql, windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After installed Wsl and Docker, can't access PSQL and other things.

I was studying Docker, and installed the latest version.
So far so good, I received an error about the WSL version, saw some tutorials and downloaded version 2.
But now that I've set up these things,
I can't access postgreSQL without running as an administrator,
pageAdmin4 itself doesn't open on its own;
I always need to manually start from the task manager...
Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: Could you provide more clarity on what you are trying to achieve and what is your actual question? It is helpful to give details and context about your setup: is your postgres server installed on the host OS, WSL, or some docker container, where are you trying to actually run the server from, etc ? Note that Windows, WSL, and Docker containers operate as separate entities so you need to set them up individually to do whatever you want.